# How to break a long shell command into a multilines separated by `\`?

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh

I need to run a series of long lines of bash commands. On each try, I need to change some parameters and rerun the command.

I know the best case is to break the lines with `"\"`, but that is only possible to *append* parameters.

Is there a way to ***inject*** a `"\" + "\n"` in the **middle** of a long bash command? Something like `Shift+Enter` or `Ctrl+Enter` in most editing environments.

For example, I've recalled the command below from the history and I want to edit it from:

```bash
$ execute_command -a /path/to/file -b another_option -c third_option
```

to:

```bash
$ execute_command \
  -a /path/to/file \
  -b another_option \
  -c third_option
```

**ANSWER**

Based on the suggestion from @benjamin-w, one can use `Ctrl-X-E` key combination. This opens the default editor, you can break your existing command into multiple lines separated by `"\"`, and upon exit puts it on the command line.

Comment: Please share your command

Comment: i think you mean you're editing on the command-line, the cursor is in the middle of a long command, and you wants to insert a newline to break the command onto two lines. i know of no way to do that, but could you say a bit more about why you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: Depending on what the goal is (also, Bash or Zsh?), in Bash/Readline, you can use `Ctrl-X-E` to open the current command in an editor.

Comment: @BenjaminW. your solution just works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `v` is technically "unbound" in most documentation, but when I am typing *on the command line* (in `vi` mode) and need to edit I hit `<ESCAPE>v`. I run in `vi` mode all the time (`set -o vi`), so this drops my whole current command buffer into a `vi` session where I can use the full power of the editor to add line breaks, correct spelling and punctuation, rethink my logic, etc. before submitting the buffer. When you save and exit `vi`, the saved buffer is fed to the parser a line at a time as if you'd done them sequentially on the command line.

Just be aware that when you exit, the buffer WILL execute whether you save or quit with no changes, so if you don't want it to do anything, save your work somewhere with `:w somefile`, then delete ALL the lines and SAVE the buffer as you exit. An "empty" buffer is the only no-op.

I can't find documentation on this at the moment, but I've used it for decades in HPUX & SunOS ksh as well as various versions of linux bash.

Otherwise, I recommend copy, cancel, paste into your favorite buffer/editor, fix it, copy, then paste back into the command line, lol

---

### Old Answer

---

As you said, backslash-escape a newline and the parser will effectively ignore it.

```
$: echo \
> this \
> is \
> all
this is all
```

Just make sure it is the LAST character of that line.
c.f. [this page](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169504&seqNum=10#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20break,continuation%20of%20the%20previous%20line.) for more.

Any properly quoted newline can be included in your output, since they are now part of the data.

```
$: echo "
> this
> is
> all"

this
is
all
```

You can also pass them as data *individually*.

```
$: echo this $'\n' is $'\n' all
this
 is
 all
```

Comment: You missed the point of my question. I know how to do multi-line commands; I am looking for a way to easily edit a currently long command to multi-line without executing it.